# How to check if an array contains a string in a different order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

Basically what I am trying to do is to search for a string in my array

This used to be my code:

```
var arr1 = ['23456', '34567', '45678', '56789', '6789T', '789TJ', '89TJQ', '9TJQK', 'TJQKA'];
var arr2 = ['98TJQ'];
var arr3 = ['89TJQ'];

if (!('containsU' in Array.prototype))
    Array.prototype.containsU = function(arr, startIndex) {
        for (i in arr) {
            if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i) && ''.indexOf.call(this, arr[i], startIndex) === -1) return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
if (!('containsArrayU' in Array.prototype)) //contains array unordered
    Array.prototype.containsArrayU = function(arr, startIndex) {
    for (i in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(i) && arr.containsU(this[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

I am looking for any element of arr1 that is part of arr2 or arr3, example:

```
arr1 = ['222','333','444','555','666','777','888','999','TTT','JJJ','QQQ','KKK','AAA'];
arr2 = ['9229'];
arr3 = ['9299'];
alert(arr2.containsArrayU(arr1)); //this should be false
alert(arr3.containsArrayU(arr1)); //this should be true (contains '999')
```

Comment: why are you using `hasownProperty` on an array?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: because it gives me errors when I iterate on the prototypes

Comment: Lots of strangeness in your code. The `containsArrayU` function iterates of the array of strings and passes the string to `containsU`, but then `containsU` iterates of the characters of the string using `for-in` and checks to see if that character is in the array by converting the array to a string via `String.prototype.indexOf`?

Comment: ...so basically your code checks to see if any character in the search string is present in any character of the strings in the array.

Comment: yes something like that, containsU returns true if the first string contains the second. And containsArrayU iterates on the array of strings

Comment: Yes maybe, it's just that sometimes I use it with arrays of other elements, in this example I had something like [[6,7,8,9,'T'],[7,8,9,'T','J']]

Comment: to me it's not even clear what the search criteria should be

Comment: I am looking to '9229' and '9929' to have 3 nines or something in arr1.

Comment: OK...so if all of the string characters of any element in arr1 are within arr2 or arr3 (whichever is passed as argument)?

Comment: so a simple solution might be to remove matches once found

Comment: Wait, you're not looking for exact matches?

Comment: I am looking for any element of arr1 to be part of arr2 or arr3

Comment: But by element, you are talking about the whole string, `89TJQ` and `98TJQ` are not equivalent

Comment: it's inside, not in the same order. it's like the same hand in a poker game.

Comment: Excuse me, explain why `9229` should be false, but `9299` should be true.

Comment: because one element is '999' so the 3 characters are inside 9299 but not in 9229

Comment: i see; token comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved it:

```
var arr1 = ['23456','34567','45678','56789','6789T','789TJ','89TJQ','9TJQK','TJQKA'];
var arr2 = '98TJQ';
var arr3 = '89TJQ';

if (!('removeAt' in String.prototype))
    String.prototype.removeAt = function(index) { return this.slice(0, index) + this.slice(index+1); };
if (!('containsU' in String.prototype)) //string contains each element of another string
    String.prototype.containsU = function(str, startIndex) {
        var newString = this;
        for(i in str) { 
            if(str.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                var index = newString.indexOf(str[i]);
                if (index===-1) return false;
                newString = newString.removeAt(index);
            }
        } return true;
    }
if (!('containsArrayU' in String.prototype))  //contains some element in array
    String.prototype.containsArrayU = function(arr, startIndex) { 
        for(i in arr) { if(arr.hasOwnProperty(i) && this.containsU(arr[i])) return true; } return false; };

alert(arr2.containsArrayU(arr1));
alert(arr3.containsArrayU(arr1));

arr1 = ['222','333','444','555','666','777','888','999','TTT','JJJ','QQQ','KKK','AAA'];
arr2 = '9229';
arr3 = '92422';
alert('9299'.containsU('999'));
alert(arr2.containsArrayU(arr1)); //this should be false
alert(arr3.containsArrayU(arr1)); //this should be true
```

[**jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/h136s7bt/3/)

All I did was to change arr2 and arr3 to the format of each element in arr1 (a string, this can probably be translated very easily to arrays).

To look for repeated numbers in the string I created a temporal one and deleted the characters already searched.